# Select by ID on a FACE using API/Macros

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

Im attempting to create a bolt generator in Solidworks using an API. One of the features ive included allows the user to emboss text on the bolt head using the Solidworks wrap function. When this is recorded for the macro the face which the wrap is applied to is SelectbyRay. The issue with this is I have many bolt sizes so the Array will change every single time, so I need to select the face by its ID. Below is the code

```
Part.SketchManager.InsertSketch True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Sketch6", "SKETCH", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Boss-Extrude1", "FACE", D2 / 2, L1, 0#, False, 4, Nothing, 0)
'boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByRay(1.74532925199433E-02, 1.74532925199433E-02, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, 0, 0, False)
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Sketch6", "SKETCH", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Boss-Extrude1", "FACE", D2 / 2, L1 + H1, 0#, False, 4, Nothing, 0)
'boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByRay(1.74532925199433E-02, 1.74532925199433E-02, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, 0, 0, False)
Dim myFeature As Object
Set myFeature = Part.FeatureManager.InsertWrapFeature2(0, 0.0001, False, 0, 1)
Part.ClearSelection2 True
```

The lines which have been commented out are the recorded array macros and above them is my attempt at trying to identify the face based on the parts toolbar within Solidworks.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to cycle through all the faces with [GetFaces](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IBody2~GetFaces.html) or [GetFirstFace](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks~SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IBody2~GetFirstFace.html), then find the face you want by looking at their parameters (iscylinder, isplane, area, diameter etc...)